# How to merge monitors using more than one PC?

Tags: networking, multiple-monitors, display, input-director

I have few PCs at my corporation which have monitors attached to them.  Is there software (or other solution) that will allow me to use all of the monitors to share a view from one (main) PC.

I've been using Input Director up until this point, but it only moves the pointer and keyboard across the views. I'd like to move windows from one monitor to another while still having access to the same clipboard, etc.

Comment: not really. That didn't make a whole lot of sense, to me anyhow. What is it you want to do ?

Comment: Are you trying to control multiple computers using one computer? Are you running linux or windows on these machines? Since it's hard to understand what you're trying to do, can you please draw a diagram or explain a bit more clearly?

Comment: Yes... sorry to heap on if perhaps English is not your native language but what you are asking is extremely difficult to figure out.  Please try to clarify.  I don't think any of us would offended if you literally went step by step... by the numbers :)

Comment: Yep, sure, it's quite hard to understand, even for me from this point. My point is to control only one PC, but using 3 monitors (1 from controled PC, 2x attached to other PC). So, I work on only 1 PC, but I can move windows between 3 monitors. Hopefuly, this is much better explained. Sorry for 1st unreadable post.

P.S. I run all machines on M$ OSes.

Comment: OK.  I think I grasp what you want better now.  You made my eyes bug out and a few of my coworkers to boot :)  I gotta admit... I don't think this is doable.  If it is... you just made a monkey out of me and I suggest when you get it going you come raz me about it :)  Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: Are you essentially saying you want a VGA / keyboard / mouse duplicator ? That would give you the same picture on all three monitors, and any mouse/keyboard would control it.

Comment: What OS?  You using Linux?  This should be doable with X11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is one of the systems a Mac?  Then look at [air display](http://avatron.com/apps/air-display).

> Ever wish you had an extra display for your computer? There’s an app
>   for that! With Air Display, you can extend your desktop wirelessly to
>   your iPad, iPhone, iPod touch or Mac as a wireless display.

If you are using Linux then [DMX](http://dmx.sourceforge.net/) may be what you want.

> Xdmx is proxy X server that provides multi-head support for multiple
>   displays attached to different machines (each of which is running a
>   typical X server). When Xinerama is used with Xdmx, the multiple
>   displays on multiple machines are presented to the user as a single
>   unified screen.

For Windows look at [Maxivista](http://www.maxivista.com/).

> MaxiVista allows you to use a Laptop as a second monitor for your
>   primary computer. No extra multi monitor hardware is required. Simply
>   extend program windows across multiple screens as if it were one big
>   monitor.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-monitor#Multiple_PC_multi-monitor

Comment: That's just what I've been looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like ["Mouse Without Boarders"](http://blogs.technet.com/b/next/archive/2011/09/09/microsoft-garage-download-mouse-without-borders.aspx) will do what you are looking for.